# Cannot do the sum of numbers using a comma and string tokenizer

Tags: java, addition, stringtokenizer

I have a program but I dont know specifically what my mistake is or how to fix it: The question is:
Write a program that asks the user to enter a series of numbers separated by commas.
The program should calculate and display the sum of all the numbers.
For example,  if I enter 4,5,6,7, the sum displayed should be 22.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumAll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userNumber;
        String sum = null;

        //get numbers from user and store
        System.out.println("Enter numbers seperated by coma's: ");

        userNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = userNumber.split("[, ]");

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            sum = tokens.length[i++]; //showing me error here. Its written array required but int //found. 
        }

        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: You cannot do arithmetic with strings, you'll have to convert them into numbers first.  Also, as the compiler tells you, to access the *i*-th element of `tokens`, use `tokens[i]`.  Finally, you are re-assigning `sum` in every iteration rather than adding to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum should be an int

```
int sum = 0;
```

Your for loop should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
      sum += Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]); 
}
```

Comment: You are already incrementing `i` in the `for` declaration for every iteration. There's no need for an extra increment in `sum = tokens[i++];`. Also, you are overriding `sum`'s value in every iteration. It should be `sum += tokens[i];`

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. I totally forgot about parsing. Thought I should use String instead of int. Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Because it should be:

```
sum += Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong with this one line of code.

```
sum = tokens.length[i++];
```

1. You can't index the `length` of the array like that. Just index the array (see below).
2. The for loop is already incrementing `i`. You don't need to do it again.
3. You need to convert the token to an integer before you can add it to the sum.
4. You need to add the new value to the sum, not replace the old sum.

Try this instead:

```
sum += Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
```

You'll also need to make `sum` an integer. Instead of

```
String sum = null;
```

you need

```
int sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I am more than 2 years late but I started learning Java not too long ago and would like to share my solution. :) I used the StringTokenizer class. I hope this helps someone out there in 2017 and onward.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class SumOfNumbersInString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a Scanner object
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get user input
        System.out.print("Enter a series of numbers seperated by commas\n> ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Display sum by calling the getSum method
        System.out.println("SUM: " + getSum(input));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param input with the format --> (#,#,#,#)
     * @return sum of numbers in the input
     */

    public static int getSum(String input) {

        // Declare and initialize the sum accumulator variable
        int sum = 0;

        // Create a StringTokenizer object 
        // The string to be tokenized is passed as 1st parameter
        // The "," that separates tokens/numbers is the 2nd parameter
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, ",");

        // The hasMoreTokens method of the StringTokenizer class returns true if there are more tokens left in the string
        // Otherwise, it returns false
        while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            // While the string has another token (number), parse the number to an integer and add its value to sum
            sum += Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
        }

        // Return sum's value to the method call
        return sum;
    }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter a series of numbers seperated by commas
> 4,5,6,7
SUM: 22
```

Answer (score 0):

/** @author Jerry Urena **/

```
public static void main(String[] args)     
{
    String userinput;
    int total = 0;

    //keyboard function
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   

    //Ask for input
    System.out.print("Please enter a series of numbers separated by commas " );

    //Get user input
    userinput = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Split numbers
    String[] numbers = userinput.split("[,]");

    //String loop
    for (String number : numbers) 
    {
        //Sum of numbers 
        total += Integer.parseInt(number); 
    }

    //Print results
    System.out.println("Total: " + total);          
}
```